# Nagios: NRPE cannot return output more than 1024 bytes

Tags: monitoring, nagios, amazon-ami, nrpe

I am using AWS in which I am using **Nagios Core 4.2.4** to monitor nodes having **NRPE agent v2.15** in AMI

Problem is the output from NRPE agent from node to Nagios monitoring server is getting truncated after ***1KB*** whereas it should be limited to ***4KB*** in the first place as per documentation.

I tried to increase values of those limits and tried recompiling as per [patch](https://buildhost.jacobs-university.de/package/view_file/jsj/nagios/nagios-output-length.patch?expand=1&rev=b78aa984d34034f347131a2ee0eee573) but thats not working

I then installed new **NRPE v3** where it says the limits have been increased to ***64K*** but I still keep getting output value no more than ***1KB***.

Not sure if there's a conflict because when I run this from Nagios monitoring server I get

> /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H slavenodeIP
>
> NRPE v2.15

but when I run this from both server and slave I get same output

> /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe | grep -i version
>
> Version: nrpe-3.0

Just to confirm if my setup makes sense

Nagios Monitoring Server -> Nagios Core + NRPE

Slaves to be monitored -> NRPE + Plugins(For eg check_nrpe )

So does that mean I am using NRPE v3 and NRPE Plugins v2.15 which conflict? Has anyone faced this issue and how did it get resolved? Been lurking on google since long time but couldn't get a fix for it

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade both the NRPE agent on the target and the NRPE plugin on the monitoring server. Only v3.x of the plugin will be able to parse the bigger packet.

Good news, though:

- EPEL has RPMs for that if you're okay with v3.1.1.
- So far I haven't found a backward compatibility issue with NRPE v2 commands;
- You also get their improved SSL bit sizes (up to 2048 bits).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check it out.